# Google Actions rejected in review due to "Mic is open" issue

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm having trouble submitting my Google Actions skill (this skill is Dialogflow based).
This is the message after submitting my skill.

```
Your Action leaves the mic open for a user command without a prompt, such as a greeting or an implicit or explicit question.
Note: Thank you for submitting your Assistant Action for review. 
However, your Action has been rejected for the following: 
1. Your Action violates our User Experience policy. Specifically, your Action listens for a user command by leaving the mic open without a prompt such as a greeting or an implicit or explicit question. 
After the Action responds to "メニュー画面”, the mic remains open without a prompt back to the user. 
For example, 
User:メニュー画面 
Action: *Mic is open* At this point, either prompt the user with further options or close the Action.
```

After reading the feedback, I understand that the phrase `メニュー画面` causes the microphone issue.
I've tried to enter this phrase `メニュー画面` in my Google Assistant application on iOS and my phone just opens the Setting menu without giving a defined response as I configured in Dialogflow intent.
I've tried to enter this phrase on Google actions web console in Phone mode and nothing happen and the request is empty

[Empty response on Google actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fqsv.png)

My expectation after entering this phrase: Google actions won't detect any intent that matches this phrase and the DefaultFallback intent will be triggered and Google will reply with some defined responses.

What can I do to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory translation of "メニュー画面" seems to be "Menu screen".

When you're using Dialogflow, the "Default Fallback Intent" will catch any user utterance that does not match another intent. You should make sure this fallback tries to rescue the conversation by reprompting them or ending the conversation.

This means that in practice asking them a question or closing it.

Because once the Action is given this prompt, the surface will open the microphone and listen for the next user utterance. However, if the response is not a question, the user may not know to say something.

Reprompting the user can be a matter of good design or just as simple as adding something like "What do you want to do?" at the end of each response.

Alternatively, you can just mark the conversation as over. This will not reopen the microphone after its response.

Comment: I've already added this phrase メニュー画面 (Menu screen) into the training phrase list of Default Fallback Intent but it doesn't change anything.
The console still replies with the earcon icon and the Default fallback intent is not triggered.